# Can browser cookies be protected (in Firefox)?

Tags: firefox, security, encryption, passwords, cookies

I read an article about identity hijacking that caught my mind.

Today I save my credentials locally in Firefox (using a master password). I also use multi-factor-authentication for important sites. I thought that my accounts would be safe even if a spyware would be installed on the PC since the password-file is encrypted and even if the password file was cracked the attacker would still need my phone to log in to important sites.

The article describes a (dark-net) site that sells identities in the form of infected PCs. When you buy an identity you can access some form of cloned instance of the PC. When you run the cloned machine you have access to all cookies which in many cases store the session  tokens, which make login a rare experience on many sites. This means that the person who have access to the clone can access most of your sites (maybe with some limitations, e.g. they need the actual password to change it).

My thought on this was that it would be valuable to also encrypt cookie data, the same way the account passwords is currently protected, so that it would require the master password to decrypt or use it.

A quick search on Google (relating to Firefox) gave nothing on this. Maybe this is not an issue, if the attacker has access to the PC there is no security in the world that can help, e.g. they can use a key logger to get the master password anyway etc.

Comment: If you are worried about it, regularly clear your cookies, and do not use "Remember Me" when logging into sites. otherwise what you suggest is the exact opposite of the design goal for long-lived auth cookies. Also, review your assumptions about your password manager. many password managers use keys related to the users login (eg Windows Data Protection API), so while they are encrypted at rest, the compromised user has access to them. review the specifics of your browsers implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought that my accounts would be safe even if a spyware would be installed on the PC since the password-file is encrypted and even if the password file was cracked the attacker would still need my phone to log in to important sites.

It's the second authentication factor that saves you: as soon as software is installed that can access files as *you*, it could just wait until you've unlocked your keyring and then read the memory of the firefox process to get the password, to decrypt the keyring. Or it could just instruct your firefox to do what it wants as "you" in the background.

> The article

which article?

> describes a (dark-net) site

ah, the dark net. Which is mostly a made-up term for "things that are perfectly publicly available but might not be on Google for the terms that most users look for".

> site that sells identities in the form of infected PCs.

like... a web forum.

Yes, these things exist.

> When you buy an identity you can access some form of cloned instance of the PC. When you run the cloned machine you have access to all cookies which in many cases store the session tokens, which make login a rare experience on many sites. This means that the person who have access to the clone can access most of your sites (maybe with some limitations, e.g. they need the actual password to change it).

Usually, you just export the cookie cache and local storage of the browser to replicate your own browser on a different device (this is perfectly normal "user profile sync" as supported by browsers intentionally!).

No need to ship a full machine image. That seems useless and excessive.

> My thought on this was that it would be valuable to also encrypt cookie data, the same way the account passwords is currently protected, so that it would require the master password to decrypt or use it.

As said, if someone has access to these files, it's game over: they will also have access to the data necessary to decrypt them, or directly to their decrypted version, from the RAM that firefox uses.

So, no, aside from *snake oil*, no such functionality will exist. Your best bet is using 2-factor authentication and keeping your PC safe. Which practically mostly still means keeping it updated, only installing software from sources you're sure you can trust, and not opening suspicious email attachments.

Comment: Thanks, the article is in Swedish:
https://www.dn.se/sald-identitet/